# as3 application build error: ios_version_min argument is missing period as second character

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I have an as3 application and I receive this error message when I try to debug the app on an iOS device or when I try to make a build:

```
"Error occurred while packaging the application:

ld: -ios_version_min argument is missing period as second character
ld: -ios_version_min argument is missing period as second character
Compilation failed while executing : ld64"
```

With AIR 16 everything goes well, but with any higher version of AIR (17, 18 or 19) I receive this message.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: What ANE are you using?

Comment: I'm using GoViral ANE from Milkman and one ANE create inside our company for Google Analytics. It's strange because I create a new project and implement these ANEs and works, but my existing app doesn't work. I also removed the anes from the app and still doesn't work, so maybe the problem is not caused by ANEs.

Comment: you do specify a min ios version like this: <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
   <string>6.0</string>?

Comment: Yes, I do. I removed it and it works now.Thanks a lot! But how can I specify in other way the minimum os version?

Comment: I just think there was a typo in yours, I use AIR 17 and minimum version 7.0 and have no problem compiling.

Comment: Ok, I'll find a way to make it work. Thanks again!